# The function should return a char from a list of binary, but I get "invalid literal for int() with base 2"

Tags: python-3.x, function

```
def binToChar(b):

    a=','.join([str(i) for i in b])
    a = int(a, 2)
    if a < 26:
        return chr(ord('A')+a)
    elif a < 52:
        return chr(ord('a')+a-26)
    elif a < 62:
        return chr(ord('0')+a -52)
    else:
        if a == 62 :
            return "+"
        if a == 63:
            return "/"


print(binToChar([1,0,1,0,1,0]))
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/assignment1/venv/tester.py", line 46, in 
> print(binToChar([1,0,1,0,1,0]))
> File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/assignment1/venv/tester.py", line 23, in binToChar
> a = int(a, 2)
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: '1,0,1,0,1,0'

Comment: What are you trying to do? What type is the parameter `b`? Given a specific input, what output do you expect?

Comment: Why are you stitching the stringified zeroes and ones together with `,`? Seems like you just want `''.join`, not `','.join`.

Answer (score 0):

The message tells you exactly what is wrong: "1,0,1,0,1,0" is not a valid number in base 2.  You want "101010" instead.

To do that, change

```
a=','.join([str(i) for i in b])
```

to

```
a=''.join([str(i) for i in b])
```